# Error in conversion of string to date

Tags: java, android, string, date

I am trying to convert string value to date but its not working

```
Date dat1;
System.out.println("String date is "+tdate);// this shows 20141015

try{
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");  
    dat1 = dateFormat.parse(tdate);

    }                           

catch(Exception e){

   System.out.println("error");

   }
```

`tdate` is String variable. The code did not show any error it runs fine but
it prints error of catch block and does not execute the code in try 
please help thanks.

Comment: Post your string "dat1", it may in another format of date.

Comment: Your Date seems `20141015` then you should change your dateformat with `SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");`

Comment: @SadiaAsghar your wel come...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
Date date = formatter.parse(tdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

The format does not match the way the date is written. Use this instead:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
```